# Im trying to setup my raspberry pi zero 2w to automatic start an rtsp server when booting

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, services

When trying to start my service called: v4l2rtspserver.service it gives me:

> Failed to start v4l2rtspserver.service: Unit v4l2rtspserver.service has a bad unit file setting.
> See system logs and 'systemctl status v4l2rtspserver.service' for details.

It seems that my service has a bad unit file setting. This is my service unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=v4l2rtspserver rtsp-server
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl vertical_flip=1
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl h264_i_frame_period=5
ExecStart=/home/pi/v4l2rtspserver/ v4l2rtspserver -F 30
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Type=simple
User=pi
Group=video
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What do I need to change to make it work? I follow this tutorial:

https://id.nl/zekerheid-en-gemak/alarm-en-beveiliging/alarm-beveiliging/zelfbouw-ip-camera-in-5-stappen

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to remove the space character from the third `ExecStart`:

```
ExecStart=/home/pi/v4l2rtspserver/v4l2rtspserver -F 30
```